# Show that given five points in $\mathbb{Z^2}$ there are at least one pair of them whose middle point also lies in $\mathbb{Z^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

While brushing up on my old discrete mathematics skills I stumbled upon this problem that I can't solve.

In $\mathbb{R^2}$ the middle point of two coordinates is $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2}{2})$. Show that given five points in $\mathbb{Z^2}$ (points with intetger coordinates) there are at least one pair of them whose middle point also lays in $\mathbb{Z^2}$. Let us consider the corresponding question in $\mathbb{R^3}$. How many points in $\mathbb{Z^3}$ would you need to be sure that at least one pair of them has a middle point in $\mathbb{Z^3}$?

I am thinking that using the **pigeonhole principle** is appropriate, how I would use it is unclear to me though.

[[image: points in <span class=]$\mathbb{Z^2}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4WxU.png)

Comment: The secret word is *parity*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_i,y_i), i = 1,2,3,4,5$ be those $5$ points.

Consider the parity of each $x_i, y_i$. There are four possible combinations:

Odd-odd, odd-even, even-odd, even-even.

By **pigeonhole principle**, at least $2$ points are in the same category.

Since odd-odd=even and even-even=even, the two points in the same category will have a midpoint in $\mathbb Z^2$ (since the difference of the points in both coordinates are divisible by $2$)

Can you see how this generalizes to higher dimensions?

Comment: @zwim Which 16?

Comment: For $\mathbb{R^3}$ we would have $2^3=8$ combinations of parities meaning the answer would be that I would need 9 points to be sure that at least one pair of them has a middle point also in $\mathbb{Z^3}$. Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. And we need $2^n+1$ for $\mathbb Z^n$.

Comment: Do you mean $2^n + 1$ for $\mathbb{R^n}$ and not $\mathbb{Z^n}$. For some reason using $\mathbb{Z^n}$ seems incorrect.

Comment: Your points are in $\mathbb Z^n$. You wish to find points such that their midpoints are also in $\mathbb Z^n$. But all these points are their midpoints are all in $\mathbb R^n$ because $\mathbb Z^n \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. The points in $\mathbb Z^n$ are called lattice points. Are you confused yet?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P=(a,b)$ and $Q=(c,d)$ be two points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. The midpoint will itself be in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ if and only if the two pairs of numbers $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ have **both** the same parity.

Since there are only four possibilities of pairing parities, as soon as you have a 5th point you must have two of the same parities.

Thus the answer comes from an application of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: what is the parity of a couple ?

Comment: @zwim: the parity of the pair $(x,y)$ is the pair $(\epsilon,\eta)$ where $\epsilon$ is the parity of $x$ and $\eta$ the parity of $y$. In other words, the parity of $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}$ is its image in $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$ under the canonical "quotient modulo $2$" map

Comment: I understand your answer, but compared to mathma one, I find it very unclear and confuse, same for player3235.

Comment: @zwim: mathma, player3236 and myself are saying exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be your set of points and consider a map $f:\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}^2$, where $f(x,y)$ is the tuple with the parity of each coordinate, e.g. $f(3,2)=(-,+)$. Then $|\mathcal{P}|=5> |\{\pm 1\}^2|=4$, so by the pigeonhole principle you will have at least two points with the same parity tuple. So their midpoint has integer coordinates.

For three dimensions you want to look at $\{\pm 1\}^3$, what is the cardinality of this set? This will tell you the necessary size for $\mathcal{P}$.